# Django - CSS not showing

Tags: python, css, django

I am having troubles loading my CSS files in for a Django Project. The HTML templates display fine, but no CSS is applied. I have included snippets of the files below. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
...
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
...
```

**project tree**

```
projectName
|   appOne
|   |   templates
|   |   |   appOne
|   |   |   |   index.html
|   appTwo
|   projectName
|   |   settings.py
|   static
|   |   css
|   |   |   style.css
|   templates
|   |   base.html
```

Comment: In the webserver log, do you see the GET request for `css/style.css`, and is it using the correct url path?

Comment: There is no GET request at all

Comment: Odd.  When you load the page in your browser and view the source, is the css link present in the header?

Comment: Yes, when I view the page source I see `href="/static/css/style.css"`. Clicking on that gives me a `PAGE NOT FOUND http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css`

Comment: Okay, so it's looking in `[WEBROOT]/static/css/style.css`, which is apparently the wrong place.  What is your web root directory?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'web root' directory I have `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` and `TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` if that's what you mean?

Comment: In `settings.py` put a `print(STATICFILES_DIR)` and see what the directory path is. Confirm that it's the same directory structure you have on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `STATIC_ROOT` to your `settings.py`?
Add path to your static file into `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: I hadn't, but setting `STATIC_ROOT = '/staticfiles/'` doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Replace `/staticfiles/` with `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`. and also run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Ok, just changed to `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` ... still no change :(

Comment: Does your root url pattern contains following?


`urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: Yes it does, and I have also run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear. I have gotten it working. After reading the latest comment I realized `STATICFILES_DIR` should be `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Thank you all for the help troubleshooting this.